# Automated publish Data Factory generate ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

For some reason the NPM package creates an "invalid" arm template. Not the one that I expected.
The arm template has no pipelines datasets etc.

What could be the issue here? I have a publish_config file and the package.json file in the root folder of my collaboration branche.
The build pipeline is in a shared branche and its triggered from the main branche to release to dev, test and prod.

Hope I can get some help.

Package.json

```
{
    "scripts":{
        "build":"node node_modules/@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities/lib/index"
    },
    "dependencies":{
        "@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities":"^0.1.3"
    }
}
```

Pipeline:

```
trigger:
#- master 
feature/npmv2 branch

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:


- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    verbose: true
  displayName: 'Install npm package'



- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run build validate $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) /subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/df-dev-0001'
  displayName: 'Validate'

# Validate and then generate the ARM template into the destination folder. Same as clicking "Publish" from UX
# The ARM template generated is not published to the ‘Live’ version of the factory. Deployment should be done using a CI/CD pipeline. 

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run build export $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) /subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/df-dev-0001 "ArmTemplate"'
  displayName: 'Validate and Generate ARM template'

# Publish the Artifact to be used as a source for a release pipeline

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ArmTemplate'
    artifact: 'ArmTemplates'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Publish config

```
{"publishBranch":"factory/adf_publish","includeFactoryTemplate":true}
```

the output of running `run build export ...` step is:

[image]

The folder structure of the one that is failing:

[image]

The folder structure of the one that is succesfull:

[image]

Kind regards,

Dickkieee

Comment: the description is not specific enough, please clarify by providing details of the issue, what have you tried, the code and results.

Comment: @Mutaz-MSFT thanks, I added some extra information

Comment: the above looks correct. also include example of the output, and indicate where it was wrong.

Comment: @Mutaz-MSFT I added a picture where I assume it goes wrong

Comment: The logged messages `LocalFileClientService: Unable to list files for ...` basically mean that the corresponding folder for the ADF artefact does not exist  on the file system or does not contain any files. This is possible if your code branch does not have artefacts the artefact in there. 

check your code branch that triggers this build pipeline, does it have all the ADF artefact json files  in there?

Comment: @Mutaz-MSFT, thanks for the anwer, that could be the case. I added two new picture, one with the folder SRC (the code branch, and the one that doesn't work) and one with my "own" test branche (that one is working succesfully. It seems that the folder structure is different. Is that the issue? And how can I fix that in the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235047/discussion-between-mutaz-msft-and-dick-ter-schiphorst).

Answer (score 0):

The logs indicate that the needed ADF json artefacts are not present in the folder from which you are running the build command.

your npm build package.json should be in the same folder as your ADF json artefacts, you can put it in a subfolder (like build for instance)

it seems that the branch from which you are running the build pipeline does not have the latest ADF code or the code is not in the location referenced by your yamp script step (`$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)`: root of the source code in your case)

review your branching strategy, make sure the feature branch or the code branch that trigger the build procedure contain both the ADF json artefacts (the code) and the npm package.json.

Check out my article on how to you setup your dev env correctly for using ADF utilities: http://www.mutazag.com/blog/code/tutorial/adf-utils-for-publishing/

to use the npm build command from inside a build sub folder you need to change the export and validate steps in the yaml file to refer to the correct working directory as follows:

```
    - task: Npm@1
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        workingDir: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/build' #replace with the package.json folder
        customCommand: 'run build export $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/df-dev-mutaz" "ArmTemplate"'
      displayName: 'Export and Generate ARM template'
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations. I will keep you informed about the progress

Comment: please update the original post to include the images in the right place in the text and label them correctly for people to be able to follow.

Comment: Done :) One last question. I created a build folder (src\data-factory\build\package.json. How could I refer the build command to use that location? customCommand: 'run build export $(build.Repository.LocalPath) /subscriptions/xxxxx

Comment: Unfortunately I ran in another error when using the workingDir: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\a\13\s\src\data-factory\build\node_modules\@microsoft\azure-data-factory-utilities\lib\index'

Comment: I think thats related to the missing gitignore file in my repo as you mentioned in your article. Could you help me generate the npm modules folder, I'm not familiar with that. Thanks again.